# DigitalSignature itextsharp 5.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, digital-signature

Can anyone please send me the C# code for Implementing DigitalSignature with version itextSharp 5.5.1 ..

How to store the certificates from where i have to retrieve ... unable to code from Java

Comment: Please post some code on what you have tried, what's working, what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

Granted: the examples are in Java, but once you grasp the concept, go to [the C# port of the examples](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/). **Do not use the examples before you've read the book!** You need to understand the different aspects of digital signing. **Merely copying/pasting code will not work!**

I know that one is supposed to put a code sample in an answer, but the question is so broad that there are so many options to pick a wrong example and I don't want to guess what the OP is actually asking. Also: I've written a 100+ pages book on the subject. It would be madness to copy/paste those pages here.